# How to post hyperlink text in twitter using twitter4j in android

Tags: android, twitter, status, twitter4j, updates

I want to post a text on twitter which will hyperlink with one Url. is this Possible? 
any way to implement this.I read some blog and posts that this is not supported by Twitter. There is any alternate to implement this one in my android application.

M using Twitter4J . Code is below.

```
String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
String token = accessToken.getToken(), secret = accessToken.getTokenSecret();
twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(token, secret);
StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate("Listening"+"<a href "+base_link_url+"</a>");
//status.setMedia(file);
twitter.updateStatus(status);
```

This is posting hyperlink as text.
Kindly suggest me on that issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have not to do any thing.Twitter automaticaly recognize your link(URL)
Do this

```
 StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate("Listening  "+"https://www.google.co.in/");
```