# Embedding email link in Twitter Direct Message

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

how do I include an email link in a Direct Message when using Twitter4j to send them?

Thanks

Angus

Comment: Can you not simply add the email to the body of the message, and it gets parsed into  link / clickable email address -- rather like any URL gets automatically linked... ...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post hyperlink text in twitter using twitter4j in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227281/how-to-post-hyperlink-text-in-twitter-using-twitter4j-in-android)

Comment: Would that work for an email address?